# JavaMail create visible folder

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create a e-mail folder using JavaMail API like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.put("mail.imap.timeout", 1000);
props.put("mail.imap.connectiontimeout", 1000);
props.put("mail.imap.writetimeout", 1000);
props.put("mail.imap.connectionpooltimeout", 500);
props.put("mail.imap.fetchsize", "2000000");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect(host, user, pass);
Folder someFolder = store.getFolder("SomeFolder");

if (!someFolder.exists())
    if (someFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES))
        System.out.println("Folder was created successfully");
```

I can use this folder from my software: move messages to it, get message list, etc. But it is invisible to most (not all) mail clients, for example, Thunderbird. How can I create a folder which is visible for all mail clients?

Comment: Also can you post the code how you are creating the mailing folders

Comment: @mhasan updated the code

Answer (score 3):

You have to subscribe the new folder.

```
if (!someFolder.exists()) {
    if (someFolder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES)) {
        someFolder.setSubscribed(true);
        System.out.println("Folder was created successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try this and see if it lets you see all the folders user is authenticated for.

```
javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
```

Comment: I recieved: Trash, INBOX and SomeFolder.

Comment: Ok. Probably then you should get your SomeFolder

Comment: I can use it from my software: move mail to it, get mail list, etc. But it is still invisible for some (not every) mail clients, for example, Thunderbird.

Comment: Where you able to access the SomeFolder from above code?

Comment: What do you mean "from above code"? From code from your answer?

Comment: Yes you said you were able to fetch SomeFolder from above code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137644/discussion-between-andrewr-and-mhasan).

Comment: You may need to refresh the folder list in Thunderbird before you will see the new folder.  Try collapsing and expanding the folder list in the left pane.  Also, Thunderbird may be configured to only see folders under a certain "root" directory.